# Import a model in R_ Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: save

I have generated an artificial neural network in R (architecture 10x30x1, activation function = ReLU), using Keras package. I want to save this model so that I can import it at any other time without having to train it. The code that I use to save it is the following:

model %>% save_model_tf("model")

The files are generated and appear in the directory.

list.files("model")
[1] "assets"         "saved_model.pb" "variables"

However, when importing it, using the following code:

new_model <- load_model_tf("model")

It gives me this error:

Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

I don't know if you could give me a clue about what I'm doing wrong or if I'm missing a step in between.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Having just encountered this error today, I tracked down a solution.

You don't provide example code, but judging from the syntax it is adapted from [the Rstudio tensorflow tutorials.](https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/tutorials/beginners/basic-ml/tutorial_basic_regression/)

I found this thread on Github, where lots of people who had copy pasted that code had similar issues with loading models.

https://github.com/rstudio/tfdatasets/issues/53

It turns out the offending item is the `normalizer_fn` in `spec`. Getting rid of that worked on my system.

Replace:

```
spec <- feature_spec(train_df, label ~ . ) %>% 
step_numeric_column(all_numeric(), normalizer_fn = scaler_standard()) %>% 
fit()
```

With:

```
spec <- feature_spec(train_df, label ~ . ) %>% 
step_numeric_column(all_numeric()) %>% 
fit()
```

As to why? No idea. I literally started using tensorflow today.